# Two address in the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I have a model with two address in it. It's possible to use gmaps4rails to geocode the two address ? How can I configure it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's definitely possible:

- configure a standard one
- use the following in a before_save:

  Gmaps4rails.geocode(second_address)

Reference here: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Methods

Answer (score -1):

I highly recommend using [Ruby Geocoder](http://www.rubygeocoder.com/) for this job! Why?

1. It has multiple backends built-in.
2. Integrates very well into Rails.
3. Provides great methods like `nearbys` or `distance_to`.
4. Has a great [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/273-geocoder) about it.
5. And no, I'm not advertising it - I'm only a happy user ;)